# MongoDb aggregation $lookup with foreign _ids in arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm a MongoDb novice. I'm getting pretty good, but no expert yet. I'm trying setup my collections in a way that makes sense. I'd like to keep some links to foreign docs inside arrays of just _ids and also arrays of objects that have _ids.

I created a JSON doc with notes that I think fully shows what I'm trying to do...

```
// ( item ) Character Inventory/Items collection
[
    {
        "_id": "1234",
        "name": "Sword",
        "descr": "Long sword, well worn, light rust",
        "encumber": 2,
        "del": false
    },
    {
        "_id": "1271",
        "name": "Pouch",
        "descr": "Small leather waist pouch, suitable for coins",
        "encumber": 0,
        "del": false
    }
]

// ( charnpcclass ) Character Classes collection
[
    { "_id": "2", "name": "Thief", "del": false },
    { "_id": "3", "name": "Cleric", "del": false }
]

// ( charnpcalign ) Character Alignments collection
[
    { "_id": "3", "name": "Lawful Good", "del": false },
    { "_id": "4", "name": "Neutral", "del": false }
]

// ( character ) Characters collection
[
    {
        "_id": "3345",
        "name": "Offut 'Dead Dog' Dubro",
        "description": "Halfling, scruffy, looks homeless",
        "align": ObjectId("4"),
        "classes": [
            ObjectId("2"),
            ObjectId("3")
        ],
        "carrying": [
            { "itemId": ObjectId("1271"), "qty":1, "where": "Sheath inside vest", "visible": false }
            { "itemId": ObjectId("1234"), "qty":1, "where": "Sword scabbard at waist", "visible": true }
        ],
        "del": false
    }
]

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// This is my MongoDb aggregation in the REST api routes

var linkedModels = [
    {
        "$match": { "del": false }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "charnpcclass",
            localField: "classes",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_classes"
        }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "charnpcalign",
            localField: "alignId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_align"
        }
    }, {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "item",
            localField: "carrying.itemId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_carrying"
        }
    }
];
db.collection('character').aggregate(linkedModels).toArray(function (err, docs) {
    res.json(201, docs);
    next();
});


// Query for Character, return items carrying with data from items collection

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// WHAT I *WANT* IN RESPONSE...
{
    "id": "3345",
    "name": "Offut 'Dead Dog' Dubro",
    "description": "Halfling, scruffy, looks homeless",
    "align": "4",
    "classes": [
        "2",
        "3"
    ],
    "carrying": [
        { "itemId": "1271", "qty":1, "where": "Sheath inside vest", "visible": false }
        { "itemId": "1234", "qty":1, "where": "Sword scabbard at waist", "visible": true }
    ],
    "linked_align": [
        { "_id": "4", "name": "Neutral" },
    ],
    "linked_classes": [
        { "_id": "2", "name": "Thief" },
        { "_id": "3", "name": "Cleric" }
    ],
    "linked_carrying": [
        { "_id": "1271", "name": "Dagger", "encumber": 0 },
        { "_id": "1234", "name": "Sword", "encumber": 2 }
    ]
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------
// WHAT I ACTUALLY GET IN RESPONSE
{
    "id": "3345",
    "name": "Offut 'Dead Dog' Dubro",
    "description": "Halfling, scruffy, looks homeless",
    "align": "4",
    "classes": [
        "2",
        "3"
    ],
    "carrying": [
        { "itemId": "1271", "qty":1, "where": "Sheath inside vest", "visible": false }
        { "itemId": "1234", "qty":1, "where": "Sword scabbard at waist", "visible": true }
    ],
    "linked_align": [
        { "_id": "4", "name": "Neutral" },
    ],
    "linked_classes": [],
    "linked_carrying": []
}
```

The problem that I hope you noticed is just above, at bottom of JSON response example. My linked arrays are empty and I'm not sure how to solve this.

I would greatly appreciate your expert MongoDb querying advice :-)

Comment: if you are "modelling" from a fresh position, it is far better practice to instead include the foreign key within the "child" rather than an "array of children" within the "parent". The problem being that with object structures in the array you cannot directly use `$lookup` and require `$unwind` on the array to process ( this may change ). Using multiple arrays with `$unwind` can lead to a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) if not handled correctly. Also keeping the foreign key in the child scales better, since you are not creating large arrays.

Comment: @NeilLunn This makes sense if your parent is linked to exactly one child. You can see I do this in the "align". This however does not address the need for 1:N relationships like "class" and/or "carrying" as shown in my example JSON.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. Parent `{ "_id": "123" }` Children `{ "_id": 1, "parent": "123" }, { "_id": 2, "parent": "123" }` The `$lookup` operator allows retrieval of multiple or singular children if so desired by using the foreign key. In this case `"parent"` from the children. This obviates the need to store within arrays of the parent. Thus `{ "$lookup": { "from": "child", "localField": "_id", "foreignField": "parent", "as": "children" } }`. It depends on the case. With an embedded document and references inside them, then you are stuck with `$unwind`. I would separate the rels

Comment: As to the rest of your "questions" ( which probably would have been better placed here than in comments on another answer ), it becomes a little broad and the general question "here" is how to perform the `$lookup` with the existing structure seems to be addressed and now considering the present case of the cartesian product. So with specific reference to "carrying" here, then you might consider another question that spells ( pun not intended ) out your intended usage. From that information "design" becomes more relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to `$unwind` to flatten the both scalar and  sub document foreign _ids and add `$group` stage at the end of the pipeline to get back the original structure.

`$first` accumulator to keep the fields and `$push` with `$arrayElemAt` to accumulate the array values to adjust for `$unwind`

```
var linkedModels = [
    {
        "$match": { "del": false }
    }, 
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "charnpcalign",
            localField: "align",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_align"
        }
    }, 
    {
        "$unwind":"$classes"
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "charnpcclass",
            localField: "classes",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_classes"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "name": {"$first":"$name"},
           "align": {"$first":"$align"},
           "classes":{"$push":"$classes"},
           "carrying":{"$first":"$carrying"},
           "linked_align":{"$first":"$linked_align"},
           "linked_classes":{"$push":{"$arrayElemAt":["$linked_classes",0]}}
        }
    },
    {
        "$unwind":"$carrying"
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            from: "item",
            localField: "carrying.itemId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "linked_carrying"
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
           "_id": "$_id",
           "name": {"$first":"$name"},
           "align": {"$first":"$align"},
           "classes":{"$first":"$classes"},
           "linked_align":{"$first":"$linked_align"},
           "carrying":{"$push":"$carrying"},
           "linked_carrying":{"$push":{"$arrayElemAt":["$linked_carrying",0]}}
        }
    }
]
```

You don't need the `$unwind` on the scalar array (`classes`) in 3.4 version and you can replace the `{"classes":{"$push":"$classes"}}` & `{"linked_classes":{"$push":{$arrayElemAt:["$linked_classes",0]}}}`  with `{"classes":{"$first":"$classes"}}` & `{"linked_classes":{"$first":"$linked_classes"}}` respectively.

Comment: If using `$unwind` then you "should" do each `$unwind` and subsequent `$lookup` separately and paired to each other, then of course `$group` back to array form. If you do not, then you end up with a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) since the content of the first array "un-wound" will be reproduced for every item in the second array "un-wound". Ideally the model should not use arrays at all, but rather reference the foreign key to the master within the children. This also scales a lot better.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thanks for nice observation and rearranged the pipeline as you have noted.

Comment: You didn't quite get it. Unless you "go back to an array" after each pair of operations then the "cartesian product" is the result. You might want to read the link to understand that. It's an `$unwind` issue that has been around as long as the operator has existed. Heres actually a demonstration of what I mean [Aggregate $sum values from two arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28827709/2313887) though as recently edited, that problem has it's own modern handling.

Comment: @Neil Lunn  Sorry, but that's what I think I'm doing now.  Unwinding  `classes`, looking up and grouping to go back to array,  before unwinding the next array `carrying` and repeat.

Comment: Must have viewed an un-altered version of the post. Anyway, as advised to the OP, it's not the best structure and they should reconsider how they store the data and relations.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am very open to reconsider how I store the data. This is completely possible. Looking at the example I posted, how do change this data model?

Comment: @NeilLunn I have begun adding additional nested functions in the REST api to query the related collections and then insert data structures into the character query. I'm not done yet, but this will certainly work. It just doesn't feel like the right solution. Correct me if I'm wrong, and it is reasonable to do this :-)

Comment: Here's another idea: I store the itemId along with the name value when the character record is created. Item names will rarely ever change. If later someone (via admin form) changes an item name, in that route run an update to fix the name values in character "carrying" arrays. Is this a good idea?

Comment: you don't need to unwind if you are using 3.4 unless you have an array of dotted fields due to a bug https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-28717

Comment: @AsyaKamsky We know this already. It is actually mentioned a couple of times here.

Comment: I see nothing about dotted fields or reference to that bug.  Maybe it was in a comment since deleted?

Comment: I've been reading up on 1:N relationships in mongo schema's. What I'm doing (arrays of links) is "normal" for lower volume 1:Ns. @NeilLunn you recommended I reconsider my schema. What change(s) do you recommend to simplify the querying?

Comment: @Locohost I recommend that you should not be initiating a conversation with me on the comment thread to someone elses answer. I have commented on your "question post", so if you have something to discuss you can [leave a comment there](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44503863/2313887) as more appropriate. I did note there that you probably should be asking a different question instead.

Comment: @NeilLunn Thank you Neil for sharing your time and expertise. I've coded a solution in the REST api. It aggregates with $lookup as much as it can initially and then adds in the other related data in new arrays before returning. So UI makes one call and gets everything. It works well for now. I'll continue my MongoDb schema design investigation outside SO.

Comment: @NeilLunn Re-reading some of your comments. In the comment about parentId in the child, you're right, I did not follow. I do now. That's an interesting idea for keeping data, you don't want to pull in every parent query, outside the parent. I will use this schema. However this won't work for my "items" as they are generic and can be related to many diff parents. But thank you again :-)

Comment: @Veeram *Thank you* for the detailed example aggregation. I'll study it and give this a try soon. I'm accepting your answer :-)

Comment: Ok, thanks to your help and example, I have the aggregation working. However, if you want to return all fields in the original doc at the end and you have multiple $unwind-$lookup-$group stage sets, each $group is huge (all fields in original doc) and repeated for as many arrays as you want to unwind. Quite an enormous aggregation! Not sure this is actually better than my code in the REST Api, which is barely 30 lines of code and easily configurable and reusable.

Comment: You are welcome. You can use [$$ROOT](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/aggregation-variables/) expression variable in the `$project` to reference the entire document if that is what you are looking for. This will require extra `$project` after  `$match` to create a field to hold the original doc.